# Excel PowerPivot - Working out percentages for columns in a PowerPivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

For illustration, I have two columns:

```
Col1 | Col2
------------
A    | Y
A    | Y
A    | Z
B    | Y
B    | Y
B    | Z
```

My Pivot looks like the following (added Col1 as a Row and ColB as a column)

```
Col 1 | Y | Z | Grand Total
---------------------------
A     | 2 | 1 | 3
B     | 2 | 1 | 3
```

What I need is the following (order of columns is not important)

```
Col 1 | Y | Y% | Z | Z % | Grand Total
---------------------------
A     | 2 | 67 | 1 | 33% | 3
B     | 2 | 67 | 1 | 33% | 3
```

**There are only two different values in Col2**

Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: You can insert Calculated Field to PivotTable. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-values-in-a-PivotTable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77

Answer (score 1):

You can add ColB in the values section twice and the 2nd time, you can edit the settings to show the value as a **Percentage of Row total**

[image: Show value as]

**Sample Output**:
[image: Sample output]